# icon quality in home screen for iPhone, new iPad & Android

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, web-applications, homescreen

I developed my first web app http://checkamy.herokuapp.com. I'm making the app compatible to all common devices. However, I got problem in making a icon **for mobile home screen**.

I have these 2 lines in HTML:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" />
```

Resolution:

- apple-touch-icon.png -> 114x114
- apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png -> 57x57

No problem in Android, but I can't make it display properly in new iPad and iPhone 4S.

The quality is bad. Apple device seems used `apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png` as Home screen icon.

My question is:

- How can I make the icons to be good looking in new & old smartphone devices?

p.s. I want to make it compatible for old devices like Android 2.2, iPhone 3G & 4S...

FYI, I'm using Coffeescript, jQuery & Ruby on Rails to build it.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

See the Apple documentation **[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)** on specifying multiple icons for multiple resolutions.

Be aware that `apple-touch-icon-precomposed` is *not* used for a different resolution, but to indicate that the "gloss" on the image has been applied already (so iOS should not apply its own gloss on the springboard representation).

For a full set able to cope with all current iDevices at native resolution, you need something like this, where the image is actually the size quoted in `sizes=` or 57x57 if no size is quoted. :

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" /> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [The Icons Slayer](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer/). It generates a lot of seemingly sensible icon sizes for you.